# Will strategy increase the probability of winning in drawing lots?

Tags: probability

Say there are $n$ red balls and $m$ blue balls in a urn. $m+n$ people everyone withdraw a ball without returning and people draw red ball wins. It's a well known result that the odd of winning is independent of order, but if we can decide when when to draw in the process of game can we increase the probability of winning by using some strategy? Say draw the ball when first time the ratio of red against blue is greater than $n/m$.

Comment: Why wouldn’t everyone then use the same strategy, resulting in no one drawing any lots?

Comment: @amd It's like someone have the privilege to decide when to draw in the process of game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have a privileged person able to draw whenever he feels like it. This person could wait for "scenarios with better odds" to draw a red ball, but it is possible that all red balls get taken in a row, leaving nothing but blue balls. Intuitively, things could take a turn for better or for worse.

Let's say that at some point in time, there are $k$ blue balls and $l$ red balls left. This person can then decide either to pick a ball now, or wait till the next turn. The probability of picking a red ball now, equals $\frac{l}{k+l}$. If the person decides to let someone else pick first, we get:

$$\frac{l}{k+l} \cdot \frac{l-1}{k+l-1} + \frac{k}{k+l} \cdot \frac{l}{k+l-1} = \frac{l(k+k-1)}{(k+l)(k+l-1)} = \frac{l}{k+l}$$

On average, the expected probability of selecting a red ball on the next turn is the same as selecting a red ball in this turn. As such, the proposed scheme does not tend to result in a larger expected probability of selecting a red ball.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is a persuasive answer for me.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there an intuitive way to summarize your conclusion that "knowing the past never helps" in this scenario?  From information theory, one would have guessed that knowing the past provides *some* useful information.  You say it doesn't.

Comment: @David G. Stork This isn't "knowledge of the past," as we average over all possible outcomes. Instead, this is examining the effect of a privileged person being able to choose where in the drawing order they are, without knowing what anyone else before them drew.

Comment: "Without knowing what anyone else before them drew"?  Oh... then of *course*.  But the original question is entirely different:  "Say draw the ball when first time the ratio of red against blue is greater than $n/m$."  The only way that sentence makes sense is if the chooser *knows* what has been drawn.  I think you solved the simpler—"no information"—problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork actually we do know what everyone before us drew. It just doesn't help us. As the answer shows, our decision is not influenced by our current state (where we know exactly how many red and blue balls are)